# Cannot change save location for Gnome screenshot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, screenshot, dconf, gnome-screenshot

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and default screenshot save location is in Pictures.

I don't want my Pictures folder to be flooded by my screenshot so I changed it to a folder called 'Screenshots'.

But pressing <kbd>Prtscr</kbd> button always saves screenshots on Pictures even after I changed it using `dconf-editor`.

[image: Screenshot of my dconf config]

But when I manually launch `gnome-screenshot` and take a screenshot, it asks for save location and saves to that location properly.

I even tried appending **file://** before path but not working

Is there a way to change location I didn't know or is it a bug?